# shell script to delete Files and sub directories from a directory in linux

Tags: shell, find

I want to delete all files and sub directories created by using the specified files. I am currently using the command to delete files and directories

```
find . ! -name file.txt -type d -exec rm -r {} +    #this is for  sub directories
find . ! -name file.txt -type f -exec rm -f {} +    #this is for files
```

It deletes all the files and sub directories when I run these command twice but I want to delete all files and directories created leaving one file at once sort. Any help is highly appreciable.
Regards
Jitendra

Comment: I don't understand the question. Specifically, what do you mean by "created by using the specified files" and "leaving one file at once sort"? Can you add an example of a directory/file structure before and after your desired command?

Comment: Hi Benjamin, Thanks for response. As the files are having some SAR extension which when extracted it created a folder or subdirectory. And I want to delete the Files as well as subdirectory at a time. But I don't what to delete one of the file among all present in parent directory at that same point of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*GNU find* can directly delete files and directories:

```
find ! -name file.txt -delete
```

It will give error messages, because it cannot delete the directories up to `file.txt`, but everything else will still be deleted.

If you want to keep the files `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, and `file3.txt`, chain the conditions like this:

```
find ! \( -name file1.txt -o -name file2.txt -o -name file3.txt \) -delete
```

Comment: Thanks for the response  Sapanoia, Let say I have a Directory1. Within That directory I have  9 files havinf the extension .tar files which as shown below;

Comment: If you want to exclude all `.tar` files, use the command like this: `find ! -name '*.tar' -delete`.

Comment: Hi Sapanoia, still I am not able to resolve Might I won't make you clear. Sorry for this. Let say I have few files and subdirectories in a directory. I want to delete all subdirectories, few files name (file1,txt,file2.txt) but 'SAPCAR' which is another filename in that directory which I don't want to delete. Can you please recommend what should I do.

Comment: If `SAPCAR` is the only file you want to keep, `find ! -name 'SAPCAR' -delete` should suffice. For multiple file names, I have extended my answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Would you mind accepting the answer, so that the question is marked as solved?